# Solve system of equations $\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x}=\frac{10}{3}$, $x^2-y^2=8$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> Solve the system:
>   $$\begin{array}{l}\dfrac{x}{y}+\dfrac{y}{x}=\dfrac{10}{3} \\
>  x^2-y^2=8\end{array}$$

First, we have $x \ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$. We can rewrite the first equation as $$\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{xy}=\dfrac{10}{3}$$
What should I do next?

Comment: Use the same $a=x+y,b=x-y$ substitution as your previous question. For what $m,n$ do you get $ma^2+nb^2=3x^2-10xy+3y^2$?

Comment: I can tell by eye that $x=3, y=1$ is a solution

Comment: Another solution is $x=-3$ and $y=-1$. So the only (real) solutions are $(3,1)$ and $(-3,-1)$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, I don't see how I can write the second equation with $a=x+y$ and $b=x-y$.

Comment: It factors exactly the same way it does in your previous question

Comment: I meant the second. Sorry!

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, if I understand we can use $a=x+y$ and $b=x-y$ in many situations. I understood this problem. But what if we have $x^2+y^2$? Can we factor it with $a$ and $b$?

Comment: Use the same approach I laid out above and you'll get $2x^2+2y^2=a^2+b^2$.

Comment: The best idea that you should have got from the previous question is that if $a=x/y$, then the first equation gives you that $a+1/a=10/3$. Therefore, $a^2-10a/3+1=0$. From where you get $a$. Once you have $a$, putting $x=ay$ in the second equation gives you the vaue of $y$.

Comment: Wait! Maybe it was someone else who asked a question with values of $x/y+y/x$ and $x^2+y^2$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt, can I ask you sth in the chat?

Comment: About this type of systems.

Comment: Sure, you can ask in [my chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51337/this-is-the-realm-of-simply-beautiful-art).

Comment: $\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{xy}=\dfrac{10}{3} \implies 3x^2 +3y^2 =2xy\implies 3x^2 -2xy + 3y^2 = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite the first equation as

$$x^2+y^2 - \dfrac{10}{3}xy = \frac13(x-3y)(3x-y)=0$$

which yields $x=3y$ and $x=\frac y3$. Plug them into $x^2-y^2=8$ to obtain the real solutions $(3,1)$ and $(-3,-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Multiplying the first equation by $xy$ gives us

$$3x^2-10xy+3y^2=0$$

Let $a=x+y$ and $b=x-y$ to get

$$4b^2-a^2=3x^2-10xy+3y^2=0$$

$$ab=8$$

Solving for $a$ in the second equation we get $a=8/b$, and substituting into the first equation gives

$$b^2-\frac{64}{b^2}=0$$

Solving for $b$ we get $b^4=16$, which has the four solutions given by $b=\pm2,\pm2i$. Correspondingly, the solutions for $a$ are given by $\pm4,\mp4i$. Solving back for $x$ and $y$ we then get the final solutions of $(x,y)=(\pm3,\pm1)$ and $(x,y)=(\mp i,\mp3i)$.

---

Alternatively, it is easy to see we have

$$4b^2-a^2=(2b-a)(2b+a)=0$$

and hence

$$\begin{cases}2b-a=0\\ab=8\end{cases}\text{ or }\begin{cases}2b+a=0\\ab=8\end{cases}$$

which can be solved just as easily.

Answer (score 1):

Denote: $\frac xy=a$. Then from the first equation:
$$a+\frac1a=\frac{10}{3} \Rightarrow 3a^2-10a+1=0 \Rightarrow a=\frac13,3 \Rightarrow \\
x=3y,y=3x$$
Plug these into the second equation:
$$(3y)^2-y^2=8\Rightarrow y=\pm 1 \Rightarrow x=\pm 3\\
x^2-(3x)^2=8 \Rightarrow x^2=-1 \Rightarrow \emptyset.$$